# Committed before 500 STREAM

Tags: java, struts2, jetty

I'm using jetty-9.0.5.v20130815, Struts 2.3.15.1 and when I try to download a file using Chrome and just in Chrome this errors happen:

```
ERROR 17/09/2013 10:26:11
(br.com.arquimagem.support.web.struts2.interceptor.ExceptionHandlerInterceptor):Unexpected error on action: class br.com.arquimagem.support.web.action.CommonFilesAction
    org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.completeWrite(WriteFlusher.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint.onSelected(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager$ManagedSelector.processKey(SelectorManager.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager$ManagedSelector.select(SelectorManager.java:455)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager$ManagedSelector.run(SelectorManager.java:420)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:532)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:51)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:487)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:165)
    ... 8 more


2013-09-17 10:26:11.441:WARN:oejs.Response:qtp776813247-5034: Committed before 500 STREAM
2013-09-17 10:26:11.456:WARN:oejs.ServletHandler:qtp776813247-5034: /GedocLog/CommonFile
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Committed
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.resetBuffer(Response.java:999)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.sendError(Response.java:351)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.sendError(Dispatcher.java:906)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:586)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1486)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:503)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1096)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:432)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1030)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:445)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.run(AbstractConnection.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:532)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

My struts.xml:

> ```
> <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
>     <interceptors>
>         <interceptor name="customException"
>             class="br.com.arquimagem.support.web.struts2.interceptor.ExceptionHandlerInterceptor">
>             <param name="result">globalError</param>
>         </interceptor>
>         <interceptor name="customFileUpload"
>             class="br.com.arquimagem.support.web.struts2.interceptor.CustomFileUploadInterceptor">
>             <param name="result">globalError</param>
>         </interceptor>
>
>         <!-- Default Stack -->
>         <interceptor-stack name="defaultStack">
>             <interceptor-ref name="customException" />
>             <!-- <interceptor-ref name="customFileUpload" /-->
>             <!-- <interceptor-ref name="alias" /-->
>             <!-- <interceptor-ref name="prepare" /-->
>             <!-- <interceptor-ref name="i18n" /-->
>             <!-- <interceptor-ref name="chain" /-->
>             <interceptor-ref name="params" />
>             <!-- <interceptor-ref name="conversionError" /-->
>             <interceptor-ref name="validation" />
>             <!-- <interceptor-ref name="workflow"<param name="inputResultName">generalError</param
>                 </interceptor-ref-->
>         </interceptor-stack>
>
>         <!-- Upload Stack -->
>         <interceptor-stack name="uploadStack">
>             <interceptor-ref name="customException" />
>             <interceptor-ref name="customFileUpload" />
>             <interceptor-ref name="params" />
>             <interceptor-ref name="validation" />
>         </interceptor-stack>
>     </interceptors>
>
>     <default-interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
>
>     <default-action-ref name="index" />
>
>     <global-results>
>         <result name="globalError">/pages/error/general.jsp
>         </result>
>         <result name="generalError">/pages/error/general.jsp
>         </result>
>     </global-results>
>
>     <action name="CommonFile"
>         class="br.com.arquimagem.support.web.action.CommonFilesAction">
>         <result name="sendFile" type="stream">
>             <param name="bufferSize">1024</param>
>             <param name="allowCaching">false</param>
>         </result>
>         <result>/pages/resultCommand.jsp</result>
>     </action>
> </package> </struts>
> ```

Why this is happen just in Chrome and about one month?

Custom interceptors:

```
package br.com.arquimagem.support.web.struts2.interceptor;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.Collections;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import br.com.arquimagem.support.exception.InfraStructureException;
import br.com.arquimagem.support.exception.InvalidParameterException;
import br.com.arquimagem.support.log4j.InfraStructureLoggerFactory;
import br.com.arquimagem.support.web.action.AbstractBaseAction;
import br.com.arquimagem.support.web.util.MessageConstants;
import br.com.arquimagem.support.web.util.Struts2Utils;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionInvocation;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionHolder;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor;

public class ExceptionHandlerInterceptor extends ExceptionMappingInterceptor
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2677219300348931782L;

    private String            result           = AbstractBaseAction.ERROR;

    protected static Logger   logger           = InfraStructureLoggerFactory
                                                       .getLogger(ExceptionHandlerInterceptor.class);

    @Override
    public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {

        try {
            return super.intercept(invocation);
        }
        catch (InvocationTargetException e) {

            if (e.getTargetException() instanceof OutOfMemoryError) {

                publishOutOfMemoryException(invocation, new ExceptionHolder(e));
            }
            else {
                publishException(invocation, new ExceptionHolder(e));

                throw e;
            }
        }
        catch (InvalidParameterException ipe) {

            publishInvalidParameterException(invocation, new ExceptionHolder(ipe));
        }
        catch (InfraStructureException ise) {

            publishInfraException(invocation, new ExceptionHolder(ise));
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {

            publishException(invocation, new ExceptionHolder(ex));
        }

        return result;
    }

    protected void publishAuthorizationException(ActionInvocation invocation, ExceptionHolder exceptionHolder) {

        super.publishException(invocation, exceptionHolder);

        logger.error("AuthorizationException exception on action: " + invocation.getAction().getClass().toString(),
                exceptionHolder.getException());

        setErrorMessage(MessageConstants.COMMON_0003, invocation);
    }

    protected void publishInvalidParameterException(ActionInvocation invocation, ExceptionHolder exceptionHolder) {

        super.publishException(invocation, exceptionHolder);

        logger.error("InvalidParameter exception on action: " + invocation.getAction().getClass().toString(),
                exceptionHolder.getException());

        setErrorMessage(MessageConstants.COMMON_0005, invocation);
    }

    protected void publishInfraException(ActionInvocation invocation, ExceptionHolder exceptionHolder) {

        super.publishException(invocation, exceptionHolder);

        logger.error("Infra structure exception on action: " + invocation.getAction().getClass().toString(),
                exceptionHolder.getException());

        setErrorMessage(MessageConstants.COMMON_0004, invocation);
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishException(ActionInvocation invocation, ExceptionHolder exceptionHolder) {

        super.publishException(invocation, exceptionHolder);

        logger.error("Unexpected error on action: " + invocation.getAction().getClass().toString(),
                exceptionHolder.getException());

        setErrorMessage(MessageConstants.COMMON_0006, invocation);
    }

    protected void publishOutOfMemoryException(ActionInvocation invocation, ExceptionHolder exceptionHolder) {

        super.publishException(invocation, exceptionHolder);

        logger.error("OutOfMemory Exception: " + invocation.getAction().getClass().toString(),
                exceptionHolder.getException());

        setErrorMessage(MessageConstants.COMMON_0014, invocation);
    }

    public String getResult() {

        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(String result) {

        this.result = result;
    }

    private void setErrorMessage(String key, ActionInvocation invocation) {

        try {
            ((AbstractBaseAction) invocation.getAction()).addError(key, Collections.emptyList());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            ((ActionSupport) invocation.getAction()).addActionError(Struts2Utils.getTextFromInvocation(invocation, key,
                    Collections.EMPTY_LIST));
        }
    }
}
```

and my CustomFileUploadInterceptor is just extending FileUploadInterceptor.

Comment: You need to post more stuff, like the customException Interceptor's code. Please note that is never a good idea to remove so many Interceptors from a Stack unless it is completely clear what is being done.

Comment: Tks Andrea. My interceptors.

Comment: It's happen just in Chrome, any idea?